# Windows 7 Games folder very slow: it takes several seconds to open Games or to select a game

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, performance

The Windows 7 Games folder is very slow, and it appears to be CPU bound by `Explorer.exe`.  When I open it, the folder takes several seconds to load all of the games.  It also takes several seconds to select a game by pointing to it.

After I open the Games folder, `Explorer.exe` continuously uses one CPU core with about 15-20% total usage of the quad-core processor.  This does not occur unless and until I open the Games folder.  Using [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), I found some abnormal registry accesses by Explorer:

[image: Explorer.exe registry access loop]
[*Click for larger size*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICTMY.png)

These registry accesses occur non-stop, and I need to terminate and restart `Explorer.exe` through the Task Manager to recover.

Any idea what may be causing this behavior?  Rebooting doesn't solve the problem, and `sfc /scannow` exited without "find[ing] any integrity violations."

**Edit:** Explorer no longer continues to hog the CPU after closing Games, but accessing the Games folder and selecting a game is still slow.  Process Monitor still indicates that Explorer was enumerating a whole bunch of files and registry entries.  Why?

Comment: This doesn't look like abnormal registry access to me.  Then again, you need to use Process **explorer** to find out what is gathering most of the CPU time first of all. Next, a list of Explorer Shell Extensions.  No default behavior of Explorer would cause this or comes to mind.

Comment: What's abnormal about this was that it was doing this repeatedly, non-stop.  Note that I can't reproduce this behavior any longer; see edit.  The Games Explorer is still slow.  This doesn't occur when accessing other folders or when opening Control Panel.

Comment: You still haven't tried Process Explorer yet huh?

Comment: I do have Process Explorer, but I haven't used it in this case.

Comment: Is it just me or why does the "explorer" have a All_Caps extention?  .EXE when pictures of process monitor and process explorer and the stuff I have here would use a lower case extention?  Without being alarmist, there are other things about the question that might indicate a baddie, so that is what has me looking at other oddities.

Comment: Scans by Norton Internet Security do not indicate any problems.

Comment: Can you look in program files, and see if anything is there that you didnt put there , or something that shouldn't be there ? some of  The things that messed with windows.live stuff have that in common. I donno, I dont use that yet.

Comment: A scan of `Program Files`, `Program Files (x86)`, `ProgramData` and `Windows` did not find any threats.

Answer (score 2):

Games Explorer isn't a typical Explorer Windows.  It does things in the background, so my guess is a certain shell extension or Game shortcut is causing it to hang while it looks for information.

There is the options for the Game Explorer.  Try turning them off, but my #1 guess is still a Explorer Shell Extension.

Comment: I can't identify any problematic shell extension.  I tried clearing the list of hidden games and hiding some games again, and it did not help.

Comment: Did you try turning off all the  Shell extensions first?

Comment: Yes, through [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).  The folder is still slow.  Only one shell extension was added before the problem began.  I suspect the problem may be caused by an update to Windows.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @DragonLord: Uninstall the update.

Comment: All of the recent updates were security updates for Patch Tuesday which I do not want to remove.  I would rather wait for Microsoft to correct it.

Comment: I'd remove them, just out of curiousity.

Comment: None of the updates or associated vulnerabilities ([MS12-001](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-001), [MS12-004](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-004), [MS12-005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-005), [MS12-006](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms12-006)) appear to be related to the issue.  As far as I am aware, the Windows Media issue doesn't appear to be related to the Games Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the settings and tell it to not download new game info (If you haven't already).

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft [forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/windows-7-game-folder/b18a0502-e410-4d59-a5d9-30f4bf155a9a) seems to indicate that other users have had issues because video drivers were out of date. Seems simple enough, but video drivers do a lot of weird things. Check your driver, make sure you've got the latest.

Comment: Updating video drivers did not help.